# MySQL search Chinese characters

Tags: mysql, cjk

Let's say I have a row:

`一天吃一個蘋果`

Someone enters as a query:

`天蘋`

Should I break up the characters in the query, and individually perform a `LIKE % %` match on each character against the row, or is there any easier way to get a row that contains one of the two characters? FULLTEXT won't work with CJK characters.

Thanks!

Comment: That would just plain be odd for someone to even enter 天蘋 at all - first of all, it doesn't mean anything (other than "day apple" or "sky apple" or "heaven apple"). Second of all, if they are searching for something in Chinese, they would use actual words like 一天 ("a day"/"one day" or 蘋果 ("apple"). I don't think any amount of `LIKE % %` is going to help with searches that have no meaning. It's like finding "Eat an apple a day" from a search of `d app` in English.

Comment: Maybe the first word boundaries were wrong, but if someone searches for: `一天 蘋果`, the question still applies. I guess I'll have to split them.

Comment: You'll need to find some kind of parsing algorithm to determine what exactly is a Chinese "word", which can be anywhere from 1 to 5 characters (and sometimes more in the case of geography and other things). I'd start by seeing how others, like www.baidu.com or open source projects, do it. It's easier in English where words (but not proper nouns always) are split by a space character. There's always www.elance.com as well :)

Comment: What can elance do in this case? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposed you are searching for all query characters in a string and care about the character order.

First split the user query. Say `天蘋` to `天` and `蘋`.

Then construct a SQL query with `LIKE` and `%`, for example, `WHERE x LIKE '%天%蘋%'`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we need a vocabulary to perform correct chinese search. They do not have spaces yet they still have words. 
For example, we've got something like "ieatpear" on input.
We should split it into any possible amount of words of 1-4 letters.
**i** ie iea ieat e ea **eat** eatp a at atp atpe t tp tpe tpea p pe pea **pear** e ea **ear** a ar r

Than our algorhythm finds real words - I eat pear ear. On the next step we can exclude ear for it's already in pear and perform search within pre-splitted vocabulary.